# Javascript Regex: How can I surround all words starting with @ with <b> tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to surround all words in a haystack starting with @ with `<b>` tags with javascript regex. What pattern would I use?

Comment: Sample data and expected results?

Comment: Considering <b> is deprecated, you might want to try <strong>

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001285.html.  It's somewhat related but correctly points out that it is not as simple as it initially appears.

Comment: Are words defined as numbers and letters? or an characters other than a blank or newline? Basically you've told us your start point, but what is your end point? And as far as I know, the <b> tag is not depreciated, using tags for styling is what is depreciated. I believe <b> is considered "bold" in the sense of "what a bold statement" and browsers default to embolding the text. But if that is not what you intend to use the <b> tag to indicate, you should use a <span> or perhaps even a <dt> tag.

Comment: Oh sorry, you would of course want to wrap them in a <span class="foo"> tag. A span tag alone wouldn't really tell the browser anything.

Answer (score 9):

```
var sample = "@sample";
sample = sample.replace(/(^|\s|-)+@(\w+)/g, "<b>$&</b>");
//^^that's assuming you want the @ to stay
//if not, use $2 instead of $&
```

`$&` inserts the matched substring.

Using functions:

```
var sample = "@sample";
sample = sample.replace(/(^|\s|-)+@(\w+)/g, function(str) {
    return "<b>"+str+"</b>";
}
```

Using functions is a good idea when you want to have greater or finer control. You might want to process the current matched piece. Whatever you want.

See more [here at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Now I don't really know if `\w+` will match the strings you want, but if you have a regex problem, that's proper for another question.

Comment: Also, put a "g" after the regular expression to match all occurrences, like: /@\w+/g

Comment: yeah, i seemed to have realized that as you were commenting. thanks

Answer (score 0):

George's example will match everything after @, including some@email.com.
Try:

```
function BoldMyText(text) {
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var returnText = '';

    for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
         word = words[i].replace(/^@(\w+)/, '<b>$1</b>');
         returnText += ' ' + word;
    }

    return returnText;
}

var myBoldedText = BoldMyText("You should @not bold my@email.com");
```

If its not what you want.